# Changing feature attribute by selecting feature in vector layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I wanted to change a feature attribute by selecting a feature in a vector layer and opening the feature form. The following QGIS online course does only show the procedure for an older version of QGIS: https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/forms.html.

Is there a way to accomplish the same in QGIS 2.18.9?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access this functionality directly from the Identify tool.

Open the tool and check the box `auto open form`. When you click the Identify tool again on a single feature, it will open the form. Select multiple features and the usual window will open, allowing you to un-select the `auto form open` option.

To set values in this form, you have to be editing the layer.

[image]

In newer version of QGIS, you would have to open the `Identity Result Settings` and tick the check mark.

[image]

Comment: @Rakan Gharaybeh: see edits

Answer (score 3):

Select the feature that you want, open the attribute table, and select `Form` from the red box in the image below:

[image]

You will get the following:

[image]